# How can I use the SBS font in Xe|Lua|La|TeX and specify which words to replace?

Tags: luatex, fontspec

The [Sans Bullshit Sans](http://www.sansbullshitsans.com/) (SBS) font uses (currently only three) ligatures to replace words that are hard coded into the font's internal glyph substitution table.

How can I use the SBS font in Xe|Lua|La|TeX and specify which words to replace?

Comment: I'm not a fan of profanity, but with the font name abbreviated as initials (SBS), it's a good combination that I heartily endorse.  -SBS aka

Answer (score 3):

This MWE demonstrates the simple idea and that you don't need to be a "[rockstar brogrammer](http://www.sansbullshitsans.com/)": Just use fontspec and luaLaTeX ...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents,fontspec}
\begin{filecontents*}{sbs100demo.fea}
    languagesystem DFLT dflt;
    languagesystem latn dflt;

    lookup demo_bs {
        sub N S A                                           by uniE602;
    } demo_bs;

    lookup demo_bulls {
        sub S i c h e r h e i t                             by  uniE601;
        sub g e h e i m                                     by  uniE601;
    } demo_bulls;

    lookup demo_bfs {
        sub V o r r a t s d a t e n s p e i c h e r u n g   by  uniE600;
    } demo_bfs;

    feature demo {
        lookup demo_bs;
        lookup demo_bulls;
        lookup demo_bfs;
    } demo;
\end{filecontents*}

\setmainfont[%
    Extension = .ttf ,
    Path = C:/SansBullshitSans/ ,
    FeatureFile=sbs100demo.fea,
    RawFeature={+demo},
    UprightFont = {*},
]{SansBullshitSans}

\begin{document}
    Der NSA-Ausschuss berät geheim.

    Sicherheit dank Vorratsdatenspeicherung!
\end{document}
```

For more details regarding the syntax of font feature files please have a look into Adobe's [OpenType Font Feature Specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko/topic_feature_file_syntax.html)

Comment: self answers are OK within limits but did you ever have  a problem that you wanted someone else to answer? The timing seems to suggest that you had this answer in advance?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I've never ever had an answer, before or just in parallel to any of my questions, yet. The reason for the close timing might be, that this platform not only allows to answer own questions, but also offers the possibility to enter the answer together with the question - what I've done, after I've tried to solve the question on my own. I published it to get feedback regarding optimizations, e.g. how to profit from srcipt/language settings (or probably slightly off-topic: how the font's internals could be adapted to handle different script/languag combinations...

Comment: ... citing the stackexchange-newbie-tour: "Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"

Comment: yes but that means show some code (working or not working)  in the question, posting an answer makes it less likely anyone else will answer.

Comment: ahhh, I understand (I misinterpreted the checkbox below the question-editor, called "answer own question"). I promise I'll do better next time.

Comment: How do you handle spaces, as in things like 'paradigm shift'?

Comment: @IanThompson: While this `sub b i g period d a t a by uniE601;` works (substitutes the string "big.data") the following rule does not work: `sub b i g space d a t a by uniE601;` In short: I don't know.